# N4 lost data connection after Lollipop update - sign into network HOME

Tags: updates, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, data-connection

I've been unable to use the data plan on my Nexus 4 on a Straight Talk plan after updating to Lollipop.

Data's not working, and I keep getting a notification that says "Sign into network HOME". When I tap on that notification it takes me to a blank screen saying "Sign-in to network". The only options I have is in the drop down menu in the top right:

- Do not use this network
- Use this network as is

When I choose the latter, my data turns on for a second and then stops working again almost immediately.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue was caused by having Lollipop reset the default access point of the phone provider to Tmobile rather than Straight talk. Setting it to Straight Talk seems to have made it work again. Will report back if anything changes.

Comment: Any update on this? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have Nexus4 on Straighttalk with the same problem. I selected "Use this network as is" option. It worked for me